# Lazily instantiated && Singletons in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

In [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)  docs, I read that AngularJS services are:

> Lazily instantiated – AngularJS only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
>
> Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.

What are these concepts exactly? I don't have any intuition about these subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lazily instantiated – AngularJS only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.**

In your application, you might have thousands/hundreds of services created. They will not get activated when they are created. For example, see the code below

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.service('test', function() {
    this.xyz = function() {
       return one;
    };
});
```

At this point, `test` service is just defined and not activated.

```
var app2 = angular.module('app2', ['app'])
app2.service('test2', function(test) {
    this.xyz = test.xyz();
});
```

Now if you see the `test2` service is depending on `test` service. So Angular instantiates `test` service before executing `test2` service. If `test2` is not using `test`, then it does not get instantiated. Same thing is applicable to `test2`service. If none is using it, it also does not get instantiated.

**Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.**

Just imagine, you want to write a service that sends analytics from your web page to server. So, each time you use methods of service, you want to utilize the same instance instead of creating new analytics sender instance each time it's injected into any part of the application. That is what the description says. When a service code is executed a single instance is created and the same instance is passed to any part of the app where the service is injected.

At the same, imagine you have User class. You want to create new user instance for each user. You don't want the same instance to be used for every user. In such cases Service is not useful. You would use `factory` instead.